# Get test results for a given test case from azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

How can I get the list of test results for a given test case using azure devops API ?

```
var testResultsQuery = new TestResultsQuery
{
   ResultsFilter = new ResultsFilter
   {
      TestCaseId = validTestCaseId
   }
};

var testCaseResults = await _testClient.GetTestResultsByQueryAsync(testResultsQuery, projectName).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This code results in an internal error (500) from the API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the  `GroupBy` and `AutomatedTestName` properties for `ResultsFilter` too. Please specify them in `ResultsFilter`.  See below example:

```
var testResultsQuery = new TestResultsQuery
{
   ResultsFilter = new ResultsFilter
   {   
     AutomatedTestName="AutoTestName",
     GroupBy = "branch",
     TestCaseId = 149
   }
};
```

Comment: Well in my case this is not a test case that is marked as automated. Is this method restricted to automated test cases runs ?

Comment: @LiohAu According to my test. It can retrieve the history of the manual tests too. But you still need to specify the test name for `AutomatedTestName` property.